# Gradle script to replace classes and function names

Tags: java, android, build, gradle, android-studio

This is not a code question per-se.
I want to create a gradle script to change classes, functions and assets (such as XML names etc.) according to a flag raised .
for example , lets say I have a class or activity named A
if a "regular release" flag is on , I want to keep the name as A
but if a "specific release" flag is on , the class name should change to "SpecificA".

I read some of gradle documentation yet I couldn't find a script for that, any ideas?

Comment: You can read up on build types and flavors in the docs for the Android Gradle plugin at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system, which is probably the way to go. Having the build system dynamically modify your code will be difficult to do, fragile, and will play hell with incremental builds. I'd most strongly recommend against going down that road.